# C++ - Longest Common Subsequence

Tags: c++, programming-challenge, time-limit-exceeded, dynamic-programming

[Link to the Problem](https://codeforces.com/group/Ir5CI6f3FD/contest/276073/problem/Q)

Here is my code to compute the length of the longest common subsequence of two integer arrays `arr[]` and `brr[]`:

```cpp
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
//Dynamic programm solution
int mem[10004][10004];//mem[i][j] stores length of the longest common subsequence, up to index i of arr and index j of brr 
vector<int> arr,brr;
int lcs(int i,int j){
    if (i<0||j<0) return 0;
    if (mem[i][j]!=-1) return mem[i][j];// if already computed, return mem[i][j]
    else {
        int tmp = 0;
        tmp = max(lcs(i-1,j),lcs(i,j-1));
        if (arr[i]==brr[j]) tmp = max(tmp,lcs(i-1,j-1)+1);
        mem[i][j] = tmp;
    }
    return mem[i][j];
}
main(){
    int n,m;// n,m are the length of the first and second array
    memset(mem,-1,sizeof(mem));
    cin >> n >> m;
    arr.resize(n+1);brr.resize(m+1);
    for (int i = 0;i<n;++i){
        cin >> arr[i];
    }
    for (int i = 0;i<m;++i){
        cin >> brr[i];
    }
    //calculate length of longest common subsequence of two array arr and brr
    cout << lcs(n-1,m-1);
}
```

The time complexity of the above approach is O(m*n). The running time of the program exceeds 1000ms when m and n are both as large as 10000. How can I improve the above program's speed to solve this problem in the case m = n = 10000 under 1000ms ? (I was trying to solve this problem in Codeforces, and there's a test case where m = n = 10000 and my program failed to solve it under 1000ms)

Comment: [edit] your question and add a link to the programming challenge

Comment: A naive comment maybe: `if ((arr[i]==brr[j])`, then is not the solution always  `tmp = max(tmp,lcs(i-1,j-1)+1);` ? If it is true, then we can avoid calculating `lcs(i-1,j),lcs(i,j-1)`

Comment: @Damien I edited the code, but the program still exceeds 1000ms.

Comment: @WhiteTiger Please don't make changes to your code after you get a suggestion. It isn't allowed.